# xpath returning simplexmlelement object not value

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I have an xml document which I am trying to access a value of a certain child element using xpath.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url,null,true);
$value = $xml->xpath("/xxx/yyy/zzz");
```

when I use:

```
print_r($value);
```

ouputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 1003.39
        )

)
```

I can access the value of the SimpleXMLElement Object by doing the following:

```
echo $value[0]
```

however I don't want to store the SimpleXMLElement Object within $value. I want to store the objects value within $value.

e.g. I want to use:

```
echo $value
```

to return

```
1003.39
```

What do I need to change in

```
$value = $xml->xpath("/xxx/yyy/zzz");
```

in order to return the value, not the object?

p.s. If I cast to a string using (string), then my print_r or echo $value prints "Array" instead of the value!

Answer (score 1):

`->xpath()` returns an array by definition, so:

```
$result = $xml->xpath("/xxx/yyy/zzz");
$value = $result[0];
```

ANd then either:

```
$value = (string)$value;
```

Or:

```
$value = strval($value);
```

If you want the *whole* array cast to string:

```
$result = $xml->xpath("/xxx/yyy/zzz");
$result = array_map('strval',$result);
```